# WTL ListView programatically set items state

Tags: winapi, atl, wtl

While having a Listview with checkboxes, how do you programatically set all items to be checked?

Answer (score 3):

Listview checkbox state is set through the state image bits of the item state. You can change item states with the `LVM_SETITEMSTATE` message, and can apply a change to all items by passing -1 as the index.

```
// The state-image index values:
//  1 for the "unchecked" (cleared) state-image
//  2 for the "checked" state-image

int iState = 2;
LVITEM lvi;
lvi.stateMask = LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
lvi.state = INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(iState);
SendMessage(hwndListView, LVM_SETITEMSTATE, -1, (LPARAM)&lvi);
```

Comment: Or, shorter, using `CListViewCtrl::SetItemState`

Comment: any ideas on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336005/wtl-multithreading-multiple-interfaces-libraries

Comment: And what about `lvi.iItem`? Shouldn't it also be set to `-1`?

Comment: @Bart: The index is given in the `wParam` message parameter. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yes, but there's also the struct member. It is undocumented whether `wParam` and `iItem` should have the same value, and what happens if they don't.

`#define ListView_SetItemState(hwnd,i,pitem) (BOOL)SNDMSGA((hwnd),LVM_SETITEMSTATE,(WPARAM)(UINT)(i),(LPARAM)(LPLVITEMA)(pitem))` 

Again, the index `i` is set, but we have no information about `iItem`. I was wondering because I ran into some trouble with multiselection, when the values were inconsistent, but I am unsure whether this was the actual reason.

Comment: @Bart It's not undocumented. The docs clearly say that for this message only the `state` and `stateMask` fields are used.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Ah, yes, the other members are ignored. Excuse me, I should have read it more carefully.