# WTL multithreading, multiple interfaces & libraries

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, wtl

I have a Main Thread that displays an interface, within another thread created from the main thread before the Main interface is shown, I create tow other windows sequentially:
I create the first window:

```
    CWarningDlg warnDlg;
    warnDlg.Create(NULL);
    warnDlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    warnDlg.BringWindowToTop();
    CMessageLoop _Loop ;

    if(_MyAppModule.AddMessageLoop(&_Loop))
    {
        nRet = _Loop.Run();
        _MyAppModule.RemoveMessageLoop();
    }
    warnDlg.DestroyWindow();
    if (nRet == SOME_VALUE)
    {
       doSomethingElse();
    }
```

Do something else has:

```
 CActionDlg actDlg;
    actDlg.Create(NULL);
    actDlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    actDlg.BringWindowToTop();
    CMessageLoop _Loop ;

    if(_MyAppModule.AddMessageLoop(&_Loop))
    {
        CreateAnObject(); //this also launches an object Specific Worker Thread
        nRet = _Loop.Run();
        _MyAppModule.RemoveMessageLoop();
    }
```

The function CreateAnObject calls some functions from a 'ComplexObject.DLL' that create an complex object which holds the THREAD ID of the thread that called the CREATION function, it gets it with `::GetCurrentThreadId();` , while creating this complex object the GetCurrentThreadId() returns the ID of the SECOND THREAD, which is GOOD.
Now, in my CActionDialog I receive notifications from this object usind ::SendMessage(), the SendMessage function is called from within a Worker thread that is specific to the Complex Object just created.
When I receive those notifications I need to access some of that complex object values, for that I call some other functions from 'ComplexObject.DLL' which verify using the ::GetCurrentThreadId() function that the ID of the calling thread is the same as the ID of thread that created that complex object. That verification fails for me, because the functions get called using the thread ID of the MAIN THREAD, that has the Main interface GUI. 
Why is that? I cannot understand! (I hope I successfully explained myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you seem to have, from your description at least, is that whatever external API you are using via `CreateAnObject`, it restricts its further use to creation thread. Taking it as is, you are limited to making calls from the creation thread only. Whenever your code running on other theads, including thread hosting `CWarningDlg`, needs to talk to this API, you need to transfer the call to the `CActionDlg` thread and proceed from there.

Synchronization can be `SendMessage` you already do, or something safer like `PostMessage` with event/message completion notification.

Comment: But isn't it enough that CActionDialog runs in the second thread? It is local to the CreateAnObject function, from where I create that external object. Doesn't running the loop and instantiating the CActionDialog in that thread mean that I m running from that thread?

Comment: `SendMessage` "transfers" calls through magic to the thread where window was created. Event if you use pointers from there directly, that would be another thread. I suppose this is the part which confuses you. Once switched to another thread, you did not switch back and then hit thread mismatch.

Comment: isn't DispatchMessage called from within the _Loop.Run() which is in the complex object creation thread?

Comment: You write that you see main thread in action, and there you see ID mismatch. You should be able to inspect call stack from there and see where you are, esp. what message you are currently processing. And this would be a window of main thread, not `CActionDlg`.

Comment: Shouldn t that thread ID be that of Thread 2 ? Does CMessageLoop alter that by calling ::DispatchMessage ?

Comment: Does the CACtionDialog run in a different 'thread' or how.. ?

Comment: In my scenario I shouldn t see main at all... I haveno business with it... all I do is in my second thread, and yet.. CActionDialog runs with the Thread ID of the main Thread.

Comment: From your description you should not see main thread, but you see that in fact you are on it. So something does not work the way you expect. So you look at Call Stack to understand why you are on the thread you should not be on. As soon as you hit thread mismatch, you need to stop and look back to see how you got there in first place.

Comment: Yes, that is true, I should not see the main thread.. unless there is a CMessageLoop behaviour that I am not aware of..that's with a high probability too..I m looking at the stack now..

Comment: So you are under impression you create stuff on `CreateAnObject` on secondary thread. Now you found it was on main thread.

Comment: When I create the object the function that creates calls ::GetCurrentThreadID .. and it returns the ID of the Secondary thread... but CActiondDialog gets dispatched from the MAin Loop... does it have to do with where do I load libraries... ?

Comment: I do create object from the second thread... ::GetCurrentThreadID states that... after CreateAnObject() call CACtionDialog handler's get called from the wrong messageLoop (main's)

Comment: I am complete NOOB... I was already creating the same dialog using that resource in Main.. that is why I was getting the messages there..

Comment: Thank you  .. and sorry for keeping you busy with my ..lack of attention.

Comment: Hey, here's another one, if you have time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365924/getmodulehandleex-usage-example-wtl-internationalisation