# GetModuleHandleEx usage example. WTL internationalisation

Tags: winapi, mfc, atl, wtl

I am trying to do internationalization in a WTL GUI application .. in my drop down selection change handler (which is used for language selection I do something like this):

```
int selected = (int)::SendMessage(m_cbLang, CB_GETCURSEL,0,0);
HMODULE hmod;
int retCode = 0;
switch(selected)
{
case 0:
    retCode =::GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_PIN, NULL, &hmod);
    ATL::_AtlBaseModule.SetResourceInstance(hmod);
    break;
case 1:

    retCode =::GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_PIN, L"GuiLibOther.dll", &hmod);
    ATL::_AtlBaseModule.SetResourceInstance(hmod);
    break;
}
return S_OK;
```

Now, I really don't know how to use this function, although it is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , I don t know what the *lpModuleName* represents. The "GuiLibOther.dll" is a dll which contains the entire interface in another language.. all resources translated to another language.. I want the interface to change the language imediatelly after another language is selected. is this the right way?
Case 0 return hmod = NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't want to use the `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` flag unless you're passing the address of some item in the DLL, which in this case you're not.

Second the documentation implies that the DLL must already be loaded before you call `GetModuleHandleEx`. If you haven't linked it in to your .exe so that it's automatically loaded, you must use [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx).

The need to use `LoadLibrary` suggests a simplification:

```
static HMODULE hmodExe = INVALID_HANDLE;
static HMODULE hmodDLL1 = INVALID_HANDLE;
switch(selected)
{
case 0:
    if (hmodExe == INVALID_HANDLE)
        retCode =::GetModuleHandleEx(0, NULL, &hmodExe);
    ATL::_AtlBaseModule.SetResourceInstance(hmodExe);
    break;
case 1:
    if (hmodDLL1 == INVALID_HANDLE)
        hmodDLL1 = LoadLibrary(L"GuiLibOther.dll");
    ATL::_AtlBaseModule.SetResourceInstance(hmodDLL1);
    break;
```

This should let you switch resource libraries dynamically without extra overhead.

Comment: Thank you, but what if I want the interface to change language at drowpdown selection, or this isn t very practical or often met in real world applications ?

Comment: And if I want to make the changes visible on existing painted controls I have to redraw them or reinitialize right? is there a way to automate this?

Comment: @A.K you should be able to do an `InvalidateRect` on your top-level window to make everything repaint.

Comment: And yet I have a problem, this is the scenario: I have a GUI with multiple windows and dialogues and I want to change their language, I have multiple .dlls with different languages resources, I do what you say above, it works if I want to load a string from a different language string table.. BUT .. I want the child controls to get replaced with the newly selected language resources, in other words, I want the language to change instantly on every GUI element that contains static text and without flickering if possible.

Comment: @A.K that's a much deeper problem. Changing the resources doesn't help once the controls are already active. You either need to destroy the windows and regenerate them, or change the text in each one individually with `SetText` or something. I'm not aware of a framework that would help. Some kind of "skinning" platform might do it, but that only works for simple applications.

Comment: Hello, do you have any ideas on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810755/delete-shell-forlder-contents-using-ifileoperation